# How to check whether a float in C language is a Nan or not

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I used the following syntax

```
if (uf > 0x7f800000)
```

> But this is not working. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan

Comment: Assuming that `uf` is a `float` variable, then the comparison `uf > 0x7f800000` will convert the integer value into a `float` and do a straight numeric comparison.

Comment: By the way, there's almost no need to use `float` in your programs, and haven't been this side of the millennium. Use `double` instead.

Answer (score 0):

NaNs always result in false when compared using `==`, `>` or any other relational operator.  And your integer `0x7f800000` will be converted to the common type of it and `uf`.

You should use the standard [`isnan()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan) function instead.

Comment: Is there any workaround this without using a function?

Comment: Not in a portable way.  What's you're objection to using the function?  (Actually, if you look closely, it's a function-like macro, so might be less objectionable to you).